# Proper way of accessing resource file for a User Control added to DNN Module?

Tags: c#, webforms, dotnetnuke, resx

I'm working with the Christoc Module Template, trying to create a module with localized text. I've added a new User Control called **TeamList.ascx** to the project, and to the **App_LocalResources** folder I've added two new files:

**TeamList.ascx.resx** and **TeamList.ascx.fr-CA.resx** (for Canadian french).

I can include the user control in my view with no issues, but when the module loads on the page, all of the places containing localized text are blank.

I *have* tried registering the user control by including:

```
<moduleControl>
   <controlKey>Teams</controlKey>
   <controlSrc>
      DesktopModules/LTSC_DashboardModule/TeamList.ascx
   </controlSrc>
   <supportsPartialRendering>False</supportsPartialRendering>
   <controlTitle>Team Control</controlTitle>
   <controlType>View</controlType>
   <iconFile />
   <helpUrl />
   <viewOrder>0</viewOrder>
   <supportsPopUps>True</supportsPopUps>
</moduleControl>
```

...in the DNN manifest file, but it has no effect.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I think it's probably something simple.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to access the RESOURCE file, or are you trying to load the ASCX file on a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the Resource File is done by using the localization methods in DNN. You'll need to post how you are referencing the resource files to ultimately figure out what you are doing wrong.

Adding a resource file is simple, create a RESX file to match your ASCX file

TeamList.ascx would get a resource file in
App_LocalResources/ called TeamList.ascx.resx resulting in the path
/app_localresources/teamlist.ascx.resx

To access that path from code behind, you would simply call

```
var stringValue = Localization.GetString("STRINGNAME.Text", LocalResourceFile)
```

Where LocalResourceFile is inherited from PortalModuleBase (you need to have your ASCX file inherit the base class that my templates create, they inherit from PMB, or you can inherit from PMB directly.

Accessing it from within the ASCX file can be done similarly

```
<%=Localization.GetString("STRINGNAME.Text", LocalResourceFile)%>
```

Of from within controls with

```
<asp:label id="SOMEID" ResourceKey="STRINGNAME.Text" runat="server" />
```

The only other potential catch is if you are loading your ASCX file into another ASCX file, if so, you need to pass the moduleconfiguration to the child ASCX file in codebehind

I do this in the [DNNSimpleArticle module](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/dnnsimplearticle/blob/master/View.ascx.cs#L71) with

```
var mbl = (dnnsimplearticleModuleBase)LoadControl(controlToLoad);
mbl.ModuleConfiguration = ModuleConfiguration;
mbl.ID = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(controlToLoad);
phViewControl.Controls.Add(mbl);
```

Does that get you pointed in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, passing the ascx file to another ascx file is exactly what I was doing. Thanks a lot!